# changing datatype from character to date without changing the fomat of the column which is mm-dd-yyyy in R

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am new to R development ,I am facing issue in changing datatype from character to date without changing the format of the column which is mm-dd-yyyy

I am trying this to char type column in 10/24/1979:
`strptime(Balti_emp_sal$HIRE_DT,"%m/%d/%Y")` which gives default format 1979-10-24

when i do run the below command i get the desired format but not class
`strftime(Balti_emp_sal$HIRE_DT,format = "%m/%d/%Y" )` gives 10/24/1979 but as character

Comment: it didnt work as this change the format of date to Y-d-m but i want m-d-y format and class date type

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a `library(chron)` to do this like below:

```
dt <- "10/24/1979"
class(dt) #character
dt <- chron(dt, format="m/d/Y")
class(dt) #dates , times
```

As you can see the class is no longer character. If you print dt you will see dt in mdy form.
I hope this answers your problem.